# C++ function to print a set

Tags: c++

Does anyone have an idea as to why

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::string set2Str(const std::set<T> & S)
{
    std::string retstr = "{";
    typename std::set<T>::const_iterator it(S.begin()), offend(S.end());
    if (it != offend)
        retstr.push_back(*it++);
    while (it != offend)
    {
        retstr.push_back(',');
        retstr.push_back(*it++);
    }
    retstr.push_back('}');
    return retstr;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> mySet = {1, 5, 9, 69};
    std::cout << set2Str(mySet);
}
```

is outputting

```
{,,   ,E}
```

????

Also, is there a more elegant way of writing the function `set2Str`? The fencepost problem with the commas makes my procedure ugly.

Comment: probably because you don't actually attempt to convert anything to a string, you just use `string::push_back` on type `T`, when `string::push_back` is expecting a `char`.

Comment: now would be a good time to familiarize yourself with [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)? Regading why, you're pushing `int` values as `char` in a string, which is thereby consuming them as ASCII code values (which they're *not*).

Comment: C++ doesn't have a standard `toString()` like in `Java` or `.NET`. You'll have to create a separate function for primitives (such as `set<int>`), and use `std::to_string()` to convert the primitive to a string.

Comment: quickfix: `std::to_string(*it++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your algorithm does this:

```
retstr.push_back(*it++);
```

The values being punched into your target string are treated as (and converted if possible to) `char`. But `{1, 5, 9, 69}` doesn't contain `char`; it contains `int`. The result is treating them as ASCII code points, [See this table](http://www.asciitable.com), and pay particular attention to the `dec` value of each character therein. Note the value for `E`, for example.

This is one of the many purposes `std::ostringstream` was made for, and has the benefit of allowing *anything* that can be written to a character stream be representable, including utilizing custom insertion operators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::string set2str(const std::set<T,Args...>& obj)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << '{';
    auto it = obj.cbegin();
    if (it != obj.cend())
    {
        oss << *it++;
        while (it != obj.cend())
            oss << ',' << *it++;            
    }
    oss << '}';
    return oss.str();
}

// custom class to demonstrate custom insertion support
class Point
{
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Point& pt)
    {
        return os << '(' << pt.x << ',' << pt.y << ')';
    }

private:
    double x,y;

public:
    Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    // used by std::less<> for set ordering
    bool operator <(const Point& pt) const
    {
        return std::tie(x,y) < std::tie(pt.x,pt.y);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<int> si = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::set<double> sd = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5 };
    std::set<char> sc = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
    std::set<unsigned> empty;

    std::cout << set2str(si) << '\n';
    std::cout << set2str(sd) << '\n';
    std::cout << set2str(sc) << '\n';
    std::cout << set2str(empty) << '\n';

    // using custom class with implemented ostream inseter
    std::set<Point> pts { {2.2, 3.3}, {1.1, 2.2}, {5.5, 4.4}, {1.1, 3.3} };
    std::cout << set2str(pts) << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
{1,2,3,4,5}
{1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5}
{a,b,c,d,e}
{}
{(1.1,2.2),(1.1,3.3),(2.2,3.3),(5.5,4.4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert `*it++` to a string - for example using `std::to_string`. Otherwise, it might be a char and gets printed as such.

For example, in your case, you just add `69`, which is the Ascii Code for E. More likely, you want `"69"`, which you would get with `std::to_string(69)`.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the type to be in an int. The numbers are being read as ASCII. They aren't being converted to a string type.

retstr.push_back(*it++);

this line sees the ANSI/ASCII capital E not the characters '6' and ' 5'

Answer (score 0):

Using sprintf which you might not like but a way.

push_back of an int to a string is your problem.

Actually this won't work if your type is not an int so you would need to detect the type used.  Or better would be to use stringstream and convert that way.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::string set2Str(const std::set<T> & S)
{
  std::string retstr = "{";
  char buffer[20] = {0};
  typename std::set<T>::const_iterator it(S.begin()), offend(S.end());
  if (it != offend) {
    sprintf(buffer, "%u", *it++);
    retstr.append(buffer);
  }
  while (it != offend)
  {
    retstr.push_back(',');
    sprintf(buffer, "%u", *it++);
    retstr.append(buffer);
  }
  retstr.push_back('}');
  return retstr;
}

int main()
{
  std::set<int> mySet;  // // = {1, 5, 9, 69};  - didn't work with my compiler
  mySet.insert(1);
  mySet.insert(5);
  mySet.insert(9);
  mySet.insert(69);

  std::cout << set2Str(mySet);
}
```